# Um processo por vez PHP

Tags: php, processo, fila, fila-thread

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de criar uma fila de processos.

Por exemplo, sempre que eu mandar executar o arquivo `processar.php`, caso ele já esteja em execução, o mesmo aguardaria para ser executado após o término do outro. Sendo apenas executado quando estiver "livre";

Comment: O nome disso é thread, sim existe, [olha aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.thread.php) e [aqui também](http://php.net/pthreads)

Comment: Utilize **session** e thread pode ser tbm, segue tutorial http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.session.php ... usava apenas session é simples funcionando de trabalho web.

Comment: No meu ponto de vista a perunta é clara. Ele quer saber como criar uma pilha de processos....senquenciamento.

Comment: Estou reabrindo a pergunta, mas elea tem sim problemas de clareza. Você poderia explicar como está executando o arquivo? É por linha de comando? É por uma requisição HTTP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso parece muito simples.

Segundo o que descreveu na pergunta, não creio que necessita de threads, enfileiramentos, etc. Bastaria criar uma flag.

Quando executar `processo.php` crie uma flag que identifique que está em execução.

Exemplo:

```
/* 
Coloque no início do arquivo, antes de qualquer execução.
*/
if (!file_exists('processo.txt')) {
    // levanta flag
    file_put_contents(`processo.txt`, 1);
} else {
    exit; // está em execução
}


/*
aqui faz os paranauê , etc e tal
*/


/*
aqui é o final, quando terminal tudo , remove a flag
*/

unlink('processo.txt');
```

## Dica

Uma dica simples para melhorar é comparar a data e hora em que o arquivo foi criado. Se o processo durar em média 10 minutos e numa próxima execução o arquivo da flag tiver mais que 10 minutos de vida, então algo errado ou inexperado ocorreu. O que fazer nesse caso é da escolha de cada um. Pode automatizar com um alerta via email, ou pode simplesmente ignorar e excluir o arquivo e gerar um novo processo, gerar log, enfim. Não posso entrar nesses detalhes pois depende do modelo de negócio de cada um e, tentar explicar aqui tornaria a resposta muito extensa e cansativa, dispersando o foco.

## Sobre a elegância

Acredito que uma solução deve ser simples, eficiente, legível e portável antes de ser elegante.

O exemplo acima mostra o mais simples e portável possível.

É portável no sentido de que pode usar isso sob quaisquer ambientes (linux, windows, mac) e mesmo num servidor de hospedagem com recursos limitados como as hospedagens compartilhadas.

O consumo de recursos é mínimo, muito mais rápido do que gerar uma flag num banco de dados.

Também pode optar por gerar a flag nas variáveis de ambiente do Sistema Operacional, inclusive sistemas linux possui recursos como o posix. No entanto aqui já estamos criando uma complicação que na maioria dos casos é desnecessária.

Comment: Normalmente se usa algo mais robusto, pq se acontecer da máquina reiniciar com o arquivo já criado (ou mesmo se ocorrer um erro no script antes do arquivo ser deletado), o PHP não será executado mais. Talvez fosse melhor uma variável de ambiente não permanente, algo que não resistisse a um reset. Lembrando que provavelmente o autor está tentando resolver o problema no lugar errado (propvavelmente seria muito mais simples, por exemplo, usar um crontab com script de shell pra rodar o PHP uma vez só, por exemplo)

Comment: Sim , há formas diversas de resolver. Julguei desnecessário demonstrar uma técnica mirabolante e "perfeita" para uma pergunta não muito clara. Acredito que o que apresentei seja o suficiente para um propósito geral, para algo amador, simples como o descrito na pergunta. Normalmente um técnico foca demais numa solução "perfeita" sendo que muitas vezes nem há uma real necessidade. Pode resolver de forma mais adequada apenas observando o modelo de negócio.

Comment: Só achei importante mencionar, pq essa do arquivo ficar "travado" segurando a aplicação é bem comum, talvez seja legal depois vc fazer uma menção a isso só como alerta (até pq depois dá pra deletarmos os comentários daqui); PS: a outra resposta sofre do mesmo problema

Comment: Cada um escolhe qual caminho seguir, qual regra adotar caso aconteça algum problema, um travamento por exemplo. As vezes numa situação onde o sistema trava e mantém a flag ativa, pode ser um recurso útil para evitar que novos processos sejam disparados pois uma falha no sistema pode indicar outros problemas que podem afetar as próximas execuções do processo em questão, podendo causar problemas maiores. Por isso, não há como determinar/afirmar o que é adequado ou não. Mas claro, é válido alertar sobre as consequências.

Comment: Daniel Omine, fiz exatamente dessa forma, adaptado ao minha necessidade, no início achei a ação de "escrever e apagar arquivo"  ruim, deselegante, mas dessa forma resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que usar **thread** não dará certo para o que você quer, pois de acordo com minhas pesquisas, thread é um recurso que permitirá a execução em blocos paralelos, pelo que entendi você quer execução sequencial de blocos de código. Veja o que este [link](http://Pesquisando%20sobre,%20achei%20esse%20[link][1]%20que%20fala:) fala sobre as threads:

> O que são threads?
>
> Antes de responder a esta pergunta, é preciso dizer que existem dois
>   tipos de threads: Kernel Level Thread (KLT) e User Level Thread (ULT).
>   Neste artigo, vamos nos concentrar apenas nas threads do tipo ULT, que
>   são as suportadas pelo PHP.
>
> Uma ULT é um conjunto de instruções que pode ser executado em paralelo
>   com outras instruções do mesmo programa. Desta forma, quando temos um
>   dispositivo (computador) com vários processadores ou um processador
>   com vários núcleos (multi-cores), é possível colocar duas (ou mais)
>   threads do mesmo processo rodando em paralelo, cada uma em um
>   processador ou núcleo próprio. O resultado disso é uma potencial
>   melhoria na performance do processo. Ou seja, ao invés de executar
>   instrução por instrução sequencialmente, você consegue executar alguns
>   blocos de instruções em paralelo e, em determinados pontos do código,
>   exigir uma sincronização para garantir que os "resultados" ou
>   processamentos executados pelas tarefas paralelas tenham sido
>   concluídas.
>
> Uma característica importante a se destacar é que as threads
>   compartilham a mesma região de memória do processo que a iniciou.
>   Portanto, várias threads podem trabalhar sobre o mesmo dado da
>   memória. Por fazerem parte de um único processo, utilizar threads
>   normalmente tem melhor performance do que executar vários processos
>   iguais em paralelo. Por outro lado, threads precisam ter algum tipo de
>   controle sobre o acesso ao mesmo dado, já que pode existir acesso
>   concorrente.

Usar **session** como o amigo sugeriu pode resolver, se sua preocupação é o aguardo da "liberação" do arquivo `processa.php` por usuário, já que é criada uma session para cada usuário. Ou seja, você não poderá bloquear a execução do arquivo php para um usuário se um outro estiver executando-o.

Minha sugestão é que tente resolver isso usando o banco de dados, criando uma fila de execução. Você precisará de um script PHP, executado de forma assíncrona, que vai pegar do banco de dados o próximo pedido a ser processado e vai chamar a `processa.php`.
No banco de dados, você pode criar colunas para armazenar as informações pertinentes de variáveis ou até do $_POST que você viria a usar.

Answer (score 0):

Há um tempo atrás eu tive que interagir php com um pipeline escrito em bash com muitas etapas e que chamavas muitas funções python e R de forma sequencial. Entáo pensei no processo inteiro como sub-processos onde  o processo 2 só era iniciado quando o processo 1 terminasse, o 3 após o 2 e assim ia até o ultimo processo. Acho que é isso que vc está procurando correto?

A solução é usar de maneira imbricada essa combinação:

```
...
//Processo-1 iniciou a reação... e gerou um arquivo => fileResultProcesso-1.txt
...
$control-2=true;
while($control-2){
if(file_exists(/path/fileResultProcesso-1)){
 //Se o arquivo xiste é pq o processo-1 já terminou.
 //Entáo inicie o processo-2
 //Salve o resultado do processo-2 (ou uma tag qualquer)
 //COloque $control-2 = False
 //////////////////////// -- Início do processo-3
   $control-3=true;
   while($control-3){
    if(file_exists(/path/fileResultProcesso-2)){
          ... continue até terminar seus processos ....
    }//Fim do if file processo-1
   }//Fim do processo-3

 }//Fim do if file processo-1
}//Fim do processo-2
```

Nota:
Em relação a quebrar o processo no meio do caminho. Vc tem que tomar uma decisão. Vai querer reiniciar todo o processo ou vai continuar de onde parou?

O meu algorítimo deletava todos os arquivos e pastas gerados ao fim do processo. Mas eu poderia guardar todos para reiniciar de onde parou e fazer uma pequena alteração no código: verificar se o arquivo ou a sua tag existe. Se sim vá para o próximo passo.

Veja um pedaço do código na foto abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]